# select specific cluster from 'kubectl config view'

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath

I am trying to select a specific server URL from `kubectl config view`

```
kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[?(@.name == 'dev')].cluster. Server}'
```

However, this fails with:

```
 error: error executing jsonpath "{.clusters[?(@.name == dev)].cluster.server}": Error executing template: unrecognized identifier dev. Printing more information for debugging the template:
            template was:
                    {.clusters[?(@.name == dev)].cluster. Server}
```

I tested this with JSONpath.com and it's apparently valid.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the single quotes around `dev` to double quotes:

```
kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[?(@.name == "dev")].cluster.server}'
```

You can see an example [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration).

Comment: Doh. Such a simple and obvious thing... it's been a long day. Thank you sir.